# Redirect all the output to a file

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, scripting

When I run

**curl -I --silent http://ip_address:8000/xxxx -o myfile**

or

**curl -I --silent http://ip_address:8000/xxxx > myfile 2>&1**

or

**wget --spider http://ip_address:8000/xxxx >myfile 2>&1**

I see the following output (the file/folder xxxx doesnt exist) :

**ip_address - - [30/Jun/2016 07:08:29] code 404, message File not found**

**ip_address - - [30/Jun/2016 07:08:29] "HEAD /aaas HTTP/1.1" 404 -**

Is there a way to redirect this output to myFile as well ?

-I want all the output to be redirected to myFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -I --silent http://ip_address:8000/xxxx > myfile.txt
```